How can I implement a text area in React, that is manually resizable in 4 directions?
I am trying to build something of a light image editor on my web page, and I need to create functionality of adding text to the image, but the text area should be manually resizable. I've been trying to google it, but I can't seem to find anything related. Are there any pre-built tools for this?
Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

